# How to use InputRange!(dchar) with Stdin in D 2.0?

Tags: d

I'm trying to write generic code that can lex *any* stream of characters (`dchar`s) into anywhere... whether it's from a file or from `stdin` into another file or `stdout`.

How do I do this?

It seems like `stdin` and `stdout` are **painful** to use with `InputRange` and `OutputRange` (since I have to wrap them manuallly every time), and I can't use `std.stdio.Stream` because it gives me bytes, not strings... and I can't find any adapter to convert from one into the other easily.

So effectively, *I can't find a good way to use `stdin`/`stdout` in my programs*.

Is there something e.g. like .NET's `TextReader` that can abstractly read text as an `InputRange!dchar` regardless of whether its input is a string, the console, or a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper function which takes a `dchar` input range is:

```d
void func(Range)(Range input)
    if(isInputRange!Range && is(ElementType!Range == dchar))
{}
```

However, you must have an input range that gets its input from stdin. There is talk of needing to rework stdio/streaming which has not been done yet. There is an [undocumented range](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/stdio.d#L1277) of `dchar` for stdin.